# Grayscale on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, grayscale

I'm trying to get an image to transform to greyscale in Javascript using HTML5 canvas.
What the heck am I doing wrong here!? I know it's really close!

```
function convertToGreyscale(str)
{
    // Get the Canvas
    var oCanvas = document.getElementById(str);
    // Get the Canvas Context
    var oContext = oCanvas.getContext('2d');

    // Get the height & width of the canvas
    var oHeight = oCanvas.height;
    var oWidth = oCanvas.width;

    // Get the image data object
    // getImageData(startX,startY,endX,endY)
    var oImageData = oContext.getImageData(0,0,oHeight,oWidth);

    // Get the actual pixel information
    var oPixelArray = oImageData.data;
    var iLength = oPixelArray.length;

    for (var iCount = 0; iCount < iLength; iCount += 4)
    {
        var oRedPixel = oPixelArray[iCount];
        var oGreenPixel = oPixelArray[iCount+1];
        var oBluePixel = oPixelArray[iCount+2];
        var oGreyValue = oRedPixel * 0.2126 + oGreenPixel * 0.7152 + oBluePixel * 0.0722;

        // Set R,G & B to be the new grey value
        oRedPixel = oGreyValue;
        oGreenPixel = oGreyValue;
        oBluePixel = oGreyValue;

    }

    // Set the greyscale image back on the canvas.
    oContext.putImageData(oImageData,0,0);
    oCanvas.src = oCanvas.toDataURL();

}
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<div style="border: 1px solid black" onmouseover="convertToGreyscale('myCanvas')">Mouseover</div>
```

Comment: You've worked out the values of R G B pixels (e.g. oRedPixel) but you're not doing anything with them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands you're simply changing the values of oRedPixel, oGreenPixel and oBluePixel, but the actual `oPixelArray` remains unchanged.

Try directly changing the array values

```
oPixelArray[iCount] = oGreyValue;
oPixelArray[iCount+1] = oGreyValue;
oPixelArray[iCount+2] = oGreyValue;
```

And you do not need this line as a canvas does not have a `src` attribute

```
// oCanvas.src = oCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: I think he's doing it here `oContext.putImageData(oImageData,0,0)`

Comment: `oPixelArray` vs. `oImageData`

Comment: isn't `oPixelArray` just a reference (not a copy) to the actual `Uint8ClampedArray` in `oImageData.data` ?

Comment: Not sure, hence the question!

Comment: oPixelArray is a reference of the array not a copy. The individual pixel values (oRedPixel etc...) are the copies as lostsource pointed out.